# My macbook pro os x sierra 10.12.3 keeps crashing and report AirPortBrcm4360 issue

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos, hardware, crash

## My configuration :

> MacOS Sierra  10.12.3 (16D32) 
> MacBook Pro (Retina, 15', late 2013), 
> Model: MacBookPro11,2
> 2 GHz Intel Core i7 (i7-4750HQ) CPU: 4-core
> . BANK 0/DIMM0
> .. 4 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
> . BANK 1/DIMM0
> .. 4 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
> Bluetooth: Handoff/Airdrop2
> Wireless:  802.11 a/b/g/n/ac

### Step to reproduce the crash :

1. turn wifi on (sometimes crashes happened just after deactivating wifi and when the systems restarted the wifi card had disappeared, icon marked with a cross and popup saying "no wifi hardware detected")
2. disconnect any ethernet thunderbolt cable or deactivate ethernet connexion
3. simply use the computer for instance navigating with safari or chrome or wait a little doing nothing (less than 2 minutes now, but it used to be hours before the problem occurs)
4. Boom ! Black screen, fans and keyboards back lights increase activity for a few seconds and then the computer just turns off completely

#### Noticeable informations :

- bluetooth can be on or off, it doesn't matter or affect the crash
  behavior even if sometimes when I turn on the computer after a crash
  bluetooth can be activated or deactivated when it was in the opposite
  state before the crash,
- no crashes occur when connected to internet with both wifi and ethernet or just through the ethernet port only. The problem is only when the wifi is on.
- no crashes when in the mac is started in safe mode and with only wifi on
- the issue started after updating to sierra os x and prior that date I had very few crashes in years (almost none). Unfortunately my time machine copies before migrating to sierra have been overwritten with post sierra's copies

#### I have tried several solutions but the problem remains. Here is a list of the opérations I went through so far with absolutely zero success :

- Changing Mac OS X Wireless Card Country Code as explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/change-mac-os-x-wireless-card-country-code)
- removing all wifi preferences and all extensions, LaunchAgents, LaunchDeamons, Internet pluggins, etc. (both in /Libbrary/, ~/Library/, /System/Library, etc.)
- removing all my applications that could mess up with the system (brew, ports, cleaner, magicPrefs, Citrix, antivirus, etc.) and cleaned all their remaining files (such as .plist files, etc.)
- updating to os x sierra with the utilities of the recovery mode
- bootable usb key, hard drive format, os x sierra clean installation and personal data recovery with time machine
- and of course I have tried contacting the apple support (feedback/bug report messages, phone calls and several visits to the so called genius bar where all hardware tests showed nothing wrong (their conclusion : as it works fine in safe mode, it might be a software issue but they don't know where and why turning wifi on is triggering the crashes). My conviction : it is a faulty sierra wifi card driver responsible of the crashes as I always get com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360.0 crash logs after each single unwanted shutdown and few times accompanied with a com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family crash log (CCIOReporter log file).

I think all is said about my issue. And I will also provide a crash report (pretty messy) or an etreCheck reports (clearer) but both didn't give usable information. I hope my approach can help some of you solving similar issues and also that some can help me find a solution.

---

*EtrePort report extract :*

```
Les informations matérielles : ⓘ

    MacBook Pro (Retina, 15 pouces, fin 2013) 

    [Les caractéristiques techniques] - [Le guide de l’utilisateur] - [Garantie & service]

    MacBook Pro - modèle : MacBookPro11,2

    1 2 GHz Intel Core i7 (i7-4750HQ) CPU: 4-core

    8 GB RAM Pas extensible

        BANK 0/DIMM0

            4 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok

        BANK 1/DIMM0

            4 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok

    Bluetooth: Bon - Handoff/Airdrop2 disponible

    Wireless:  en0: 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac

    La batterie : Santé = Satisfaisant - Comptage de cycles = 426



Les informations vidéo : ⓘ

    Intel Iris Pro

        Color LCD 2880 x 1800



Les logiciel du système : ⓘ

    macOS Sierra  10.12.3 (16D32) - Temps depuis le démarrage : environ 2 heures



Les informations des disques : ⓘ

    APPLE SSD SM0256F disk0 : (251 GB) (Solid State - TRIM: Yes)

    [Afficher le rapport SMART]

        EFI (disk0s1)   : 210 Mo 

        Recovery HD (disk0s3)   [Restauration] : 650 Mo 

        Macintosh HD (disk1) /  [Startup] : 249.78 Go (50.76 Go libre)

            Crypté AES-XTS Ouvert

            Core Storage: disk0s2 250.14 Go Online



Les informations USB : ⓘ

    Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad 

    Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub 

        Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 



Les informations Thunderbolt : ⓘ

    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

        Apple Inc. Thunderbolt to Gigabit Ethernet Adapter



Les fichiers de configuration : ⓘ

    /etc/sudoers, Taille du fichier 2299 mais 1563 prévu



Le gatekeeper : ⓘ

    Mac App Store et développeurs identifiés



Les agents de lancement systèmes : ⓘ

    [engagé]    com.apple.LocalAuthentication.UIAgent.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.NowPlayingTouchUI.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.accessibility.dfrhud.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.controlstrip.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.eosauthagent.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.eospreflightagent.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.imautomatichistorydeletionagent.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.screencapturetb.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.touchbar.agent.plist (2017-01-13)

    [désengagé]    7 tâches d’Apple

    [engagé]    168 tâches d’Apple

    [en marche]    95 tâches d’Apple



Les daemons de lancement systèmes : ⓘ

    [engagé]    com.apple.biokitaggdd.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.biometrickitd.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.eoshostd.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.nfcd.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.nfrestore.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.seld.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.touchbar.user-device.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    com.apple.xartstorageremoted.plist (2017-01-13)

    [engagé]    org.cups.cupsd.plist (2017-01-13)

    [désengagé]    40 tâches d’Apple

    [engagé]    151 tâches d’Apple

    [en marche]    110 tâches d’Apple



Les éléments Ouverture : ⓘ

    iTunesHelper    Application   (2017-02-13)

        (/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunesHelper.app)

    SpeechSynthesisServer    Application  

        (/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesisServer.app)



Les extensions de Safari : ⓘ

    Save to Pocket 

    

Les panneaux de préférences tiers : ⓘ

    Flash Player (2016-12-16) [Aide]



Le Time Machine : ⓘ

    Ignorer les fichiers du système : NON

    Sauvegardes mobiles : Allumé

    Sauvegarde automatique : OUI

    Disques sauvegardés :

        Macintosh HD : Taille de disque : 249.78 Go Disque utilisé : 199.02 Go

    Destinations :

        My Book 1 [Network] 

        Taille totale : 2.00 To 

        Nombre total de sauvegardes : 26 

        Sauvegarde la plus ancienne : 29/12/2016 19:38 

        Dernière sauvegarde : 17/02/2017 04:28 

        Taille du disque de sauvegarde : Excellent

            Taille de sauvegarde 2.00 To > (Taille de disque 249.78 Go X 3)



L’utilisation du CPU par processus : ⓘ

         6%     WindowServer

         3%     kernel_task

         1%     fontd

         1%     Google Chrome Helper(38)

         1%     com.apple.AmbientDisplayAgent



L’utilisation de la RAM par processus : ⓘ

    3.39 Go     Google Chrome Helper(38)

    839 Mo      kernel_task

    328 Mo      Google Chrome

    270 Mo      WindowServer

    213 Mo      Mail



Les informations de la mémoire virtuelle : ⓘ

    2.05 Go     RAM disponible

    22 Mo       RAM libre

    5.95 Go     RAM utilisé

    2.02 Go     Fichiers en cache

    2 Mo        Fichier d’échange utilisé
```

---

*AirPortBrcm4360 log extract :*

```
Feb 17 02:40:38.185638 +0100 000001.629593 Brcm4360[279] [0xf285b62e64aa2843][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::configHandler: PCIe config handler: [ARPT], message[0xe0000210] state[3] timestamp[0x0000000000000000] calendartime[0x000548b00030a6a4]

Feb 17 02:40:38.185741 +0100 000001.629696 Brcm4360[281] [0xf285b62e64aa2843][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::configHandler: PCIe config handler: [ARPT], message[0xe0000225] state[3] timestamp[0x000000000018dd9a] calendartime[0x000548b00030a70b]

Feb 17 02:40:38.185783 +0100 000001.629737 Brcm4360[284] [0xf285b62e64aa2843][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::start: this[0xf285b62f23496ec3] vendor[0x14e4] device[0x43a0] ... registerService() ... return

Feb 17 02:40:38.185800 +0100 000001.629755 Brcm4360[285] [0xf285b62e64aa2cdb][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: messageType[0xe0000340], params(changeFlags[0x00000000] fromCapabilities[0x00000000] toCapabilities[0x0000000f])

Feb 17 02:40:38.185803 +0100 000001.629758 Brcm4360[286] [0xf285b62e64aa2cdb][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: returning: _powerState[0] _systemSleeping[0] systemWoke[0]

Feb 17 02:40:38.185859 +0100 000001.629814 Brcm4360[287] [0xf285b62e652bbeeb][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateWillChangeTo: 2, timestamp[0x000000000018de74] calendartime[0x000548b00030a781]

Feb 17 02:40:38.185861 +0100 000001.629816 Brcm4360[288] [0xf285b62e652bbeeb][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateWillChangeTo: 2, ACK'ing

Feb 17 02:40:38.185872 +0100 000001.629827 Brcm4360[289] [0xf285b62e652bba53][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerState: Called powerStateOrdinal = 2, timestamp[0x000000000018de81] calendartime[0x000548b00030a78e]

Feb 17 02:40:38.185875 +0100 000001.629830 Brcm4360[290] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: powerStateOrdinal = 2, callback[2]systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[0] _powerState[0] _down[0] _up[0] osh[0xf285b62e652f9ca3]

Feb 17 02:40:38.186029 +0100 000001.629984 Brcm4360[297] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerCycleInProgress: state [0] -> [1], name['wl_fatal_error'] id[31094]

Feb 17 02:40:38.186032 +0100 000001.629987 Brcm4360[298] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerCycleInProgress: _up[0] _down[0] _powerSleep[0] _powerState[0] _powerCycleThreadWaiting[0] _powerOffOnThreadBlockedForWake[0] _powerCycleOffOnThreadRunning[0]

Feb 17 02:40:38.186080 +0100 000001.630035 Brcm4360[301] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] KMOD info(name: 'com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360' version['1130.3.1a5'] address[0xf285b62dd3585ec3] size[0x7c1000])

Feb 17 02:40:38.195335 +0100 000001.639290 Brcm4360[1803] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: Device in bad state after wakeup - err:-1

Feb 17 02:40:38.195336 +0100 000001.639291 Brcm4360[1804] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: Device in bad state after wakeup - err:-1

Feb 17 02:40:38.195338 +0100 000001.639293 Brcm4360[1805] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: returned: powerStateOrdinal = 2, callback[2] systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[0] _powerState[2]

Feb 17 02:40:38.195340 +0100 000001.639295 Brcm4360[1806] [0xf285b62e652bba53][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerState: powerStateOrdinal = 2, ACK'ing.

Feb 17 02:40:38.195357 +0100 000001.639311 Brcm4360[1809] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerCycleOffOnThread: calling setPOWER(OFF)

Feb 17 02:40:38.195359 +0100 000001.639314 Brcm4360[1810] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPOWER(): >>>> _powerState[2] _lastUserRequestedPowerState[2] _systemSleeping[0] _powerOffInProgress[0] _powerOffThreadRequest[1], _powerSleep[0] pid[0]'kernel_task'

Feb 17 02:40:38.195364 +0100 000001.639319 Brcm4360[1812] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPOWER(OFF): _powerState[2] _lastUserRequestedPowerState[2] _systemSleeping[0] _powerOffInProgress[0] _powerOffThreadRequest[1] selfpid[0] inprogress[0]

Feb 17 02:40:38.195411 +0100 000001.639366 Brcm4360[1815] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPOWER(OFF): calling changePowerStateToPriv( PS_INDEX_DOZE )

Feb 17 02:40:38.195421 +0100 000001.639376 Brcm4360[1816] [0xf285b62e652bbeeb][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateDidChangeTo: 2, timestamp[0x00000000001903cd] calendartime[0x000548b00030ccda]

Feb 17 02:40:38.195425 +0100 000001.639380 Brcm4360[1817] [0xf285b62e652bbeeb][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: powerStateOrdinal = 2, callback[3]systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[2] _down[1] _up[0] osh[0xf285b62e652f9ca3]

Feb 17 02:40:38.195428 +0100 000001.639383 Brcm4360[1818] [0xf285b62e652bbeeb][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: enabled[0] interfaceFlags[0x0822] ifup[0], timestamp[0x00000000001903d5] calendartime[0x000548b00030cce2], commandWakeup()

Feb 17 02:40:38.195466 +0100 000001.639421 Brcm4360[1822] [0xf285b62e652bbeeb][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: returned: powerStateOrdinal = 2, callback[3] systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[2]

Feb 17 02:40:38.195468 +0100 000001.639423 Brcm4360[1823] [0xf285b62e652bbeeb][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateDidChangeTo: 2, ACK'ing

Feb 17 02:40:38.195580 +0100 000001.639535 Brcm4360[1838] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPOWER(): 
Feb 17 02:40:38.195581 +0100 000001.639536 Brcm4360[1839] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerCycleOffOnThread: setPOWER(OFF) returned 0.

Feb 17 02:40:38.195584 +0100 000001.639539 Brcm4360[1841] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerCycleOffOnThread: OFF -> ON, Delaying _powerOffOnDelayms[ 300] (ms)

Feb 17 02:40:38.195596 +0100 000001.639551 Brcm4360[1842] [0xf285b62e64aa2843][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateWillChangeTo: 1, timestamp[0x000000000019047d] calendartime[0x000548b00030cd8a]

Feb 17 02:40:38.195598 +0100 000001.639553 Brcm4360[1843] [0xf285b62e64aa2843][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateWillChangeTo: 1, ACK'ing

Feb 17 02:40:38.195613 +0100 000001.639568 Brcm4360[1844] [0xf285b62e654a55e3][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerState: Called powerStateOrdinal = 1, timestamp[0x000000000019048d] calendartime[0x000548b00030cd9a]

Feb 17 02:40:38.496617 +0100 000001.940572 Brcm4360[1845] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerCycleOffOnThread: calling setPOWER(ON)

Feb 17 02:40:38.496622 +0100 000001.940577 Brcm4360[1846] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPOWER(): >>>> _powerState[2] _lastUserRequestedPowerState[1] _systemSleeping[0] _powerOffInProgress[1] _powerOffThreadRequest[0], _powerSleep[0] pid[0]'kernel_task'

Feb 17 02:40:38.496626 +0100 000001.940581 Brcm4360[1848] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPOWER(ON): _powerState[2] _lastUserRequestedPowerState[1], calling changePowerStateToPriv( PS_INDEX_ON )

Feb 17 02:40:38.496660 +0100 000001.940615 Brcm4360[1850] [0xf285b62e654a55e3][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: powerStateOrdinal = 1, callback[2]systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[2] _down[0] _up[1] osh[0xf285b62e652f9ca3]

Feb 17 02:40:38.496707 +0100 000001.940662 Brcm4360[1857] [0xf285b62e654a55e3][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: WWEN[disabled]

Feb 17 02:40:38.496844 +0100 000001.940799 Brcm4360[1864] [0xf285b62e654a55e3][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: returned: powerStateOrdinal = 1, callback[2] systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[1]

Feb 17 02:40:38.496846 +0100 000001.940801 Brcm4360[1865] [0xf285b62e654a55e3][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerState: powerStateOrdinal = 1, ACK'ing.

Feb 17 02:40:38.496863 +0100 000001.940818 Brcm4360[1866] [0xf285b62e654a55e3][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateDidChangeTo: 1, timestamp[0x00000000001d9d50] calendartime[0x000548b00035665d]

Feb 17 02:40:38.496866 +0100 000001.940821 Brcm4360[1867] [0xf285b62e654a55e3][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: powerStateOrdinal = 1, callback[3]systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[1] _down[0] _up[1] osh[0xf285b62e652f9ca3]

Feb 17 02:40:38.496869 +0100 000001.940824 Brcm4360[1868] [0xf285b62e654a55e3][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: returned: powerStateOrdinal = 1, callback[3] systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[1]

Feb 17 02:40:38.496870 +0100 000001.940825 Brcm4360[1869] [0xf285b62e654a55e3][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateDidChangeTo: 1, ACK'ing

Feb 17 02:40:38.496898 +0100 000001.940853 Brcm4360[1870] [0xf285b62e654a886b][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateWillChangeTo: 2, timestamp[0x00000000001d9d72] calendartime[0x000548b00035667f]

Feb 17 02:40:38.496900 +0100 000001.940855 Brcm4360[1871] [0xf285b62e654a886b][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateWillChangeTo: 2, ACK'ing

Feb 17 02:40:38.496912 +0100 000001.940867 Brcm4360[1872] [0xf285b62e64aa43d3][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerState: Called powerStateOrdinal = 2, timestamp[0x00000000001d9d81] calendartime[0x000548b00035668e]

Feb 17 02:40:38.496915 +0100 000001.940870 Brcm4360[1873] [0xf285b62e64aa43d3][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: powerStateOrdinal = 2, callback[2]systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[1] _down[0] _up[1] osh[0xf285b62e652f9ca3]

Feb 17 02:40:38.724489 +0100 000002.168444 Brcm4360[1880] [0xf285b62e64aa43d3][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: returned: powerStateOrdinal = 2, callback[2] systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[2]

Feb 17 02:40:38.724493 +0100 000002.168448 Brcm4360[1881] [0xf285b62e64aa43d3][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerState: powerStateOrdinal = 2, ACK'ing.

Feb 17 02:40:38.724516 +0100 000002.168471 Brcm4360[1882] [0xf285b62e652be843][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateDidChangeTo: 2, timestamp[0x0000000000211693] calendartime[0x000548b00038dfa0]

Feb 17 02:40:38.724521 +0100 000002.168476 Brcm4360[1883] [0xf285b62e652be843][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: powerStateOrdinal = 2, callback[3]systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[2] _down[0] _up[1] osh[0xf285b62e652f9ca3]

Feb 17 02:40:38.724524 +0100 000002.168479 Brcm4360[1884] [0xf285b62e652be843][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: enabled[0] interfaceFlags[0x0822] ifup[0], timestamp[0x000000000021169d] calendartime[0x000548b00038dfaa], commandWakeup()

Feb 17 02:40:38.724960 +0100 000002.168915 Brcm4360[1887] [0xf285b62e652be843][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::syncPowerState: returned: powerStateOrdinal = 2, callback[3] systemWoke[0] _powerSleep[1] _powerState[2]

Feb 17 02:40:38.724963 +0100 000002.168918 Brcm4360[1888] [0xf285b62e652be843][0][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerStateDidChangeTo: 2, ACK'ing

Feb 17 02:40:38.724975 +0100 000002.168930 Brcm4360[1889] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPOWER(): 
Feb 17 02:40:38.724977 +0100 000002.168932 Brcm4360[1890] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerCycleOffOnThread: setPOWER(ON) returned 0.

Feb 17 02:40:38.724983 +0100 000002.168938 Brcm4360[1891] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerCycleInProgress: state [1] -> [0], name['powerCycleOffOnThread'] id[5317]

Feb 17 02:40:38.724986 +0100 000002.168941 Brcm4360[1892] [0xf285b62e652bba53][1][0] AirPort_Brcm43xx::setPowerCycleInProgress: _up[1] _down[0] _powerSleep[0] _powerState[2] _powerCycleThreadWaiting[0] _powerOffOnThreadBlockedForWake[0] _powerCycleOffOnThreadRunning
...
```

---

Comment: I reported the bug through the [apple bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/logon) and gave them a thorough analyse with the terminal command "sudo sysdiagnose -t"
The answer I received is pretty puzzling from a company that own the material, the operating system and all the proprietary softwares on my computer. Basically, it is a known issue/under investigation. And I must check the release notes for changes affecting this issue.
So I tried the [beta program](https://beta.apple.com/sp/fr/betaprogram) and installed the latest 10.12.4Beta7 but it also crashes every 5 min or less :(

Comment: Have you tried downgrading to El Cap?  I have many clients (including myself) who have solved a number of Sierra issues by going back to 10.11.  If the problem persists there, then it's most likely hardware.  Also, you may wish to try running [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to verify that the Airport card is good.   Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: Thanks @Allan for the reply ! Yes, I have tried El Cap and it didn't crash my MacBook. But maybe I didn't wait enough time because unfortunately all my old Time Machine backups were overwritten and I cannot import the data from the ones made with Sierra, that's why I had to resume to the new OS. Plus the AHT didn't find any issue. I took my computer to an apple certified repair and their deep hardware tests indicate a failing mother board and they said it might be a messy [EFI update](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518). So 2 options there : change the mother board or wait for a new EFI.

Comment: If you had a "messy" EFI update, you likely wouldn't be able to boot your Mac at all.  If your logic board was failing, it would be picked up by AHT.  Here's what you can do:  go get an external drive like the [WD Passport](http://amzn.to/2ngaifd) and install El Cap to it.  Boot using the `Opt` key to select the external drive.  If all works, then you know proof positive it's not your logic board.

Comment: Hi, The apple support after telling me the issue will be corrected by an EFI update, changed the recommandation and they asked me to change the material as the issue should have been resolved by previous updates. So I have changed the logic board and it is working perfectly so far :) Thanks again for the replies !

Comment: Having the same issue with Sierra 10.12.6 on a mid-2014 MBP.   Problem started showing up after the latest system update.   HW testing shows no faults.  The local Apple repair shop is suggesting a new logic board but it is far too coincidental it started happening after an OS patch.  Anyone have a clear indication if this is a SW/Firmware issue or HW related in this case?

Comment: Got the same issue. After couple OS reinstallation and tons of googling got here. I'm going to try using the USB WiFi tonight

Answer (score 1):

What helped me:

- Using OS X Mavericks (default OS for my laptop, didn't have a chance to use Sierra/ElCapitan)
- Using any usb wifi adapter;
- Using native wifi but power adapter is connected
- Using native wifi on battery but it should be charged > 45%

What didn't help:

- OS reinstall (with/without disk formatting)
- Remove wifi, airport etc config files
- Reset SMC
- Reset NVRAM
- Look for updates (no updates available)

What I did else:

- Launched Apple Hardware test (OK)
- Launched some apple benchmarks (Geekbench 4, Blackmagic Disk speed test) (all OK)
- Launched Coconut Battery (got 7193 mAh, designed 8440 mAh)

Other problems I found:

- Can't turn the mac on (or wake it up) when the battery is low than 40%. But if I don't shut it down or hibernate it works down to 0%

I have no proofs but I think the problem is in the combination of soft wifi and battery status.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
Remove from user library, from folder preferences, the apple internetconfig files.
Examples:
 com.apple.internetconfigpriv.plist 
 com.apple.internetconnect.plist

(And any other you could find)

In addition you could remove the preferences for airport too:

com.apple.airport.preferences.plist

Remove and reboot...voila!

Comment: Unfortunately I completely reinstalled the OS and got no result (yesterday installed, today got 2 crashes)